# How to develop an outlook 2007 custom action?

Tags: c#, vsto, office-2007, outlook-addin, custom-action

I need a custom outlook rule action: "Save the email attachments to DB", for this action the attachments in that email will be automatically saved to DB.

I find a topic at MSDN [Outlook 2007 Sample Add-ins: Rules Add-in, Travel Agency Add-in, and Prepare for Meeting Add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226710.aspx) but this topic does not show how to develop a custom action.

Outlook 2007 has a "Rules Wizard" dialog, in the "Select actions" form has many actions, it is possible add my custom action into this form?

I also find a action named "perform a custom action" in the "Rules Wizard" dialog, when check this action user can open a dialog to select a custom action. How to develop a add-in which can be used in this dialog?

Comment: I have found a answer from Microsoft Communities[http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.outlook.program_addins&mid=3bb8ec33-78f4-4e29-a58f-1e4f31409f6e]

Comment: The link appears to be broken - do you have a working link, or a tip I can use to get going on writing my own custom action?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no you can't use code to extend the "custom actions" available in the Rules wizard.

You can however write custom code with an Outlook VSTO addin that will do the same thing, using the Application level events provided, such as NewMailEx etc.